# baixar e Instalar Microsoft.Speech.Recognition

Tags: c#, chatbot, reconhecimento-de-voz

Alguem poderia me informar o link onde posso baixar esta reference: Microsoft.Speech.Recognition; e se possível me auxiliasse a instalá-la.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa adicionar a referência `System.Speech` ao seu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
var sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Para mais informações do componente:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378426(v=office.14).aspx